# How can I increment/decrement non-alphanumeric ASCII values of characters in Vim?

Tags: vim, ascii

I would like to increment the ASCII value of several rows of characters. Most of them are not alphanumeric, otherwise I could simply use [`:set nrformats+=alpha` to make `CTRL-A` and `CTRL-X` work on them](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Increasing_or_decreasing_numbers). Is there any native Vim way of incrementing and decrementing ASCII values, or do I need to script it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:help nr2char
:help char2nr
```

Example:

```
:%s/./\=nr2char(char2nr(submatch(0))+1)/g
```